# android timer swing

Tags: android, timer

I need to create a Timer to update the UI at regular intervals. But the Swing Timer class is not available on Android. How can I work around this problem ?
(I would avoid creating threads and then use the Timer class from java.util package)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and the [`postAtTime()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) or the [`postDelayed()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).  This will allow you to schedule a `Runnable` to be executed at some point in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for your problem Handler class would suffice(+1 to Dave :)).
FYI, there are other classes namely [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) & [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) that can help with timing the runs of your code.